# How to handle shift pressed before another key in onkeyup?

Tags: javascript

I need to handle usb barcode scanner in my web page, all was working well on my computer but when i tried it on another one (Windows 7 and another scanner) i had an issue with shift key.

The scanner barcode has `:` symbol and when it's read it's passed like `Shift;` how can i get the real symbol from it?

Here is my function when i handle the scanning:

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
  let key = event.key;
  if (event.isComposing || key === 'Shift' || key === 'Control' || key === 'Meta' || key === 'Alt') {
    return;
  }
  
  if (containerLoading.classList.contains("d-none")) {
    showLoading();
  }
  
  if (!containerLoading.classList.contains("d-none")) {
     if (key === "Enter" || key === "Tab") {
      if (barcode != "") {
        websocket.send(`<ART>${barcode}</ART>`);
        barcode = "";
      }
    } else {
      barcode += key;
    }
  }
});
```

Here is how the scanner barcode result in notepad (and that's how it should be) and under you can find how it looks like in the browser:

[image]

TEST TEXT:

WRONG

```
Hc1ò6BFOXN%Ts3DHPVo13j -g'-2YRVa.q-r8'd32Fc1j9M$Di9CPi9ELNLAPS$SçLc-GPWBILc9Ff9

84Ev28JVSAp921TDUMx6WUKAMa800p92ò3
```

RIGHT

```
HC1ç6BFOXN%TS3DHPVO13J -G'-2YRVA.Q-R8'D32FC1J9M$DI9CPI9ELNLAPS$SçLC-GPWBILC9FF9

(4EV28JVSAP921TDUMX6WUKAMA800P92ç3
```

ENG KEYBOARD

```
HC1:6BFOXN%TS3DHPVO13J /G-/2YRVA.Q/R8-D32FC1J9M$DI9CPI9ELNLAPS$S:LC/GPWBILC9FF9

*4EV28JVSAP921TDUMX6WUKAMA800P92:3
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/getModifierState

Comment: A semicolon should be reading as code "SemiColon" in the event before the shift is fired.

Comment: @Tschallacka SemiColon was just an example i have even issues with chars like ò which sould be ç and 9 which should be ( and lot other

Comment: I presume you have a usb scanner as input? If thats the case your input is not UTF8, check the output from the scanner.

Comment: @Grumpy yes it's a USB Scanner, it's programmed to be as keyboard emulator..

Comment: Check what output is defined, just open a text editor, do a scan and check the output, if it shows the correct scan, something goes wrong when you read the input in your script.

Comment: @Grumpy in notepad i get the correct value, i've just added a screen in the question, the issue is that if i try it on my computer it returns even in js correct value..

Comment: The images are incomplete.

Comment: @Grumpy added some example text by using italian keyboard as system and an example of how it is with ENG keyboard

Comment: Its the covid qrcode, it should always start with HC1:, what scanner are you using?

Comment: @Grumpy it's a Honeywell 5680 mounted on NCR Kiosk, anyway by using a handheld datalogic the code is got correctly, i solved the issue by using keypress instead keydown without changing any other code but i would anyway know why of that behaviour..

Comment: Glad you solved it, its a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by replacing `keyup` with `keypress`

Now the code looks like this:

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {
  let key = event.key;
  if (event.isComposing || key === 'Shift' || key === 'Control' || key === 'Meta' || key === 'Alt') {
    return;
  }
  
  if (containerLoading.classList.contains("d-none")) {
    showLoading();
  }
  
  if (!containerLoading.classList.contains("d-none")) {
     if (key === "Enter" || key === "Tab") {
      if (barcode != "") {
        websocket.send(`<ART>${barcode}</ART>`);
        barcode = "";
      }
    } else {
      barcode += key;
    }
  }
});
```